# xcode 5.0.2 Code Signing Entitlements Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-entitlements, bundle-identifier

I am trying to release a second version of my app. After I released the first version of the app, I upgraded to Maverick OS and Xcode 5.0.2. After archiving the new version of the app, I tried to validate it in Xcode. I am receiving the following error:

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle
>   signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning
>   file. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key
>   value that is not allowed” ‘[“45GU53BL5Zcom.myCompany.myApp”]’ for the
>   key ‘keychain-access-groups’ in ‘Payload/myApp.app/myApp’

I do not know how to solve this problem. Perhaps it has something to do with the prefix on com.myCompany.myApp, but I did not change anything (i.e. I submitted this in the first version without error). I mean, this is just part of the application-identifier that apple assigns. Furthermore, I have another app that uses a similar application-identifier, and it validates without error using Xcode 5.0.2.

I don't even know where this application-identifier is within the bundle. Should I be editing it?

Could someone please point me in the right direction to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Select the proper Provisioning Profile in the Build Settings. There's quite a few entries in the Build Settings, if you type Provisioning Profiles in the filter box you will see the entry. Select the proper one from the select box.

Comment: I checked. 45GU53BL5Z is not part of the Bundle ID. The only place that I know this prefix exists is where the in-app purchases are defined. Each in-app purchase uses the application-identifier which includes the prefix 45GU53BL5Z.

Answer (score 0):

do you miss .p12 file in your new os system ? 
you upgraded to new os system, may be the .p12 file and the provisioning profile need add into mac again